# GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON on glutMouseFunc is not working well

Tags: opengl, glut

LEFT and RIGHT Button Mouse Events are working on the program as below.

```
    void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
    {
        if (button)
        {
            switch (state) 
            {
            case GLUT_DOWN:
                Mouse_X = x;
                Mouse_Y = y;
                break;
            case GLUT_UP:
                current = Target;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Not only LEFT Button but also RIGHT BUTTON working in case of `if (button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)` as below. Let me know how to solve it.

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        switch (state) 
        {
        case GLUT_DOWN:
            Mouse_X = x;
            Mouse_Y = y;
            break;
        case GLUT_UP:
            current = Target;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which values does button have?

Comment: RIGHT BUTTON is working, too.